# The DataSourceID of 'GridView1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, ado.net

Why i am getting following error ?
i can see data when i did a test run query !

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The DataSourceID of 'GridView1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'MyDataSource' could not be found.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The DataSourceID of 'GridView1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'MyDataSource' could not be found.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): The DataSourceID of 'GridView1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'MyDataSource' could not be found.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.GetDataSource() +8556294
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.ConnectToDataSourceView() +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +19
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927
```

Below is my source :

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="MyDataSource">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Colum1" HeaderText="Colum1" 
                SortExpression="Colum1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2" 
                SortExpression="Column2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column3" HeaderText="Column3" 
                SortExpression="Column3" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be better if you can post form design code.

Comment: Where is your data source with the id MyDataSource?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that there is no datasource control on the form with the ID `MyDataSource` which is the value of the `DataSourceID` property of the `GridView`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="MyDataSource"></asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In the above example, I used a `SqlDataSource`. However, any datasource control will do and its ID value must match the value used in the `DataSourceID` attribute of the GridView.

Another thing to check is that the markup is valid. I.e., there are no missing angle brackets, nothing outside the `form` tag. Nothing on a content page with a Master page that is outside of a content area. etc.

Comment: @SmartestVEGA - Have you verified that the markup is valid? That there is nothing outside the form tag? That anything with a master page does not contain stuff outside of a content area (including the datasource control)?

Comment: i have addded the frontend source ..please have a look

Comment: @SmartestVEGA  - Where is the datasource control?

Answer (score 4):

This can also happen when the page uses a masterpage and the `ObjectDataSource` is in the scope of a different `asp:content` control

Answer (score 0):

DataSourceID should be the ID of a datasource control on your page.  If you are binding in the codebehind then do not set the DatasourceID.

Answer (score 0):

just remove this  from the gridview :

```
DataSourceID="MyDataSource"
```

if you fill it from the codebehind

Answer (score -2):

**first goto App_Data and create xml file**

- 1-App_Data/ddlxmlFile.xml
- 2-Get xmldatasource from toolbox and give same datasourceid name to
  xmldatasource ID=""

### apply this in your code